# Is it possible to run tensorflow v1.x now on google colab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, version, deep-fake

I have been working on voice deepfake, but every program i used (for example mekatron, tacotron etc) needed tensorflow v1.x which is now unsupported on google colab, is there any way to use it? I am a begginer.

I tried use automatic update program but it always cause many errors when I try to use my program. Is there any trick or something to run program on google colab with tensorflow v2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Tensorflow 1.x` is no longer supported. Hence this code `%tensorflow_version 1.x` of changing runtime into `TF 1.x` is not working anymore.

However, You can explicitly install `tensorflow 1.x` in Google Colab to use TF 1.x functionality as below:

`pip install tensorflow==1.15`  and restart the runtime.

Or
Please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to convert your code from `TF 1.x` to `TF 2.x`.